# Javascript wrong redirecting when submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here is my javascript code to check whether the user has entered values for username and password fields. When I run this, it shows me the correct alerting messages but the form is seems to be submitted even it returns false. Can someone helps me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function loginValidate(){
       if (document.getElementById("username").value==''){
          window.alert("Please enter your username");
          if (document.getElementById("password").value==''){
              window.alert("Please enter your username and password");
        return false;
          }
       }
       if (document.getElementById("password").value==''){
          window.alert("Please enter your password");
        return false;
       }

    return true;
   }
</script>

<form onsubmit="loginValidate()">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
</form
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value returned by the function to the handler:

```
<form onsubmit="return loginValidate()">
```

Also, do not give any form control a name or id of "submit" as it assign a reference to the control to the form's *submit* property, thereby masking the form's *submit* method (i.e. `form.submit` references the control, so `form.submit()` will fail).

There is rarely any need for a submit button to have a name or id, so:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

You can also clean up the logic a bit. If you pass a reference to the form to the function, getting the controls is easier:

```
<script>
  function loginValidate(form){
    if (form.username.value == ''){
      window.alert("Please enter your username");
      return false;
    }

    if (form.password.value == ''){
       window.alert("Please enter your password");
       return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return loginValidate(this)">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Username: <td><input type="text" name="username">
    <tr><td>Password: <td><input type="password" name="password">
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: right;><input type="submit" value="Login">
  </table>
</form
```

Note that this sends the password in clear text so not particularly secure.

Comment: If it worked my friend then accept answer as correct.